# Azure Pipelines VSTest how to set name for TRX file

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

When i run my tests using the task VSTest@2 in Azure Pipelines, it generates a temporary .TRX file, I want to generate the same file but with a specific name:

It's generating like `Administrator_TFSAGNT1533-1_2022-07-20.11_50_19.trx`

I'd like to generate something like `testResults.trx`

My task

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: Unit Tests
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '*(*.Test)*(*.Integration).dll'
      searchFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\git\test-bin'
      resultsFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\git\testsResult\unitTest'
      vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
      testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=Integration'
      runSettingsFile: 'CodeCoverage.runsettings'
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure it out:
I had to add the line `otherConsoleOptions: '/Logger:"trx;LogFileName=testResults.trx"'`

```
      - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: Unit Tests
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '*(*.Test)*(*.Integration).dll'
      searchFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\git\test-bin'
      resultsFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\git\testsResult\unitTest'
      vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
      testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=Integration'
      runSettingsFile: 'CodeCoverage.runsettings'
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
      otherConsoleOptions: '/Logger:"trx;LogFileName=testResults.trx"'
```